# How to overcome error while rolling log segment for a topic in kafka streaming?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using faust kafka streaming python package, to consume the data for every 5 sec interval, whereas at some point of time, it throws an error stating that `"Error while rolling log for topic"` and after this a log of a topic is deleted automatically and unable to consume the messages after this point?

How to avoid this in faust kafka streaming python package?

```
[2020-02-07 20:03:27,692] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets 

in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2020-02-07 20:12:51,562] ERROR Error while rolling log segment for ble_rtls-1 in dir /var/lib/kafka/data (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/kafka/data/ble_rtls-1/00000000000022839498.index (No such file or directory)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply$mcZ$sp(AbstractIndex.scala:121)
at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(AbstractIndex.scala:115)
at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(AbstractIndex.scala:115)
at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.resize(AbstractIndex.scala:115)
at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply$mcZ$sp(AbstractIndex.scala:184)
at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply(AbstractIndex.scala:184)
at kafka.log.AbstractIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply(AbstractIndex.scala:184)
at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
```

Below is the log retention policy I have,

```
############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.
delete.topic.enable = false

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=1

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################
```

Comment: Are your logs mounted on a separate volume / disk than the broker OS?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. The kafka broker is in /opt/kafka/bin, whereas the log is in /var/lib/kafka both resides on the different space.

Comment: I mean physical disks or logical partitions...

Comment: @cricket_007 everything resides in a same physical disks

Comment: Best practices would suggest that is a bad idea and that you should use a JBOD for your logs anyway. https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html#disks ; not that that answers your error, but it certainly wouln't make it worse